# Google Chrome won't install via IE9/Windows7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

Using IE9, I've tried installing Google Chrome on Windows 7 from this url
http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?hl=en-GB&platform=win

But get the following error (apologies for uncouthly dumping this nonsense...)

Any ideas dearly appreciated!

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.235
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.235 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : _http://dl.google.com/update2/1.3.21.57/GoogleInstaller_en-GB.application?appguid%3D%7B8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96%7D%26iid%3D%7B26C55C3A-B26A-0484-FEDD-78443D269DA1%7D%26lang%3Den-GB%26browser%3D2%26usagestats%3D0%26appname%3DGoogle%2520Chrome%26needsadmin%3Dfalse%26installdataindex%3Ddefaultbrowser

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of _http://dl.google.com/update2/1.3.21.57/GoogleInstaller_en-GB.application?appguid%3D%7B8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96%7D%26iid%3D%7B26C55C3A-B26A-0484-FEDD-78443D269DA1%7D%26lang%3Den-GB%26browser%3D2%26usagestats%3D0%26appname%3DGoogle%2520Chrome%26needsadmin%3Dfalse%26installdataindex%3Ddefaultbrowser resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [25/06/2011 11:41:04] : Activation of _http://dl.google.com/update2/1.3.21.57/GoogleInstaller_en-GB.application?appguid%3D%7B8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96%7D%26iid%3D%7B26C55C3A-B26A-0484-FEDD-78443D269DA1%7D%26lang%3Den-GB%26browser%3D2%26usagestats%3D0%26appname%3DGoogle%2520Chrome%26needsadmin%3Dfalse%26installdataindex%3Ddefaultbrowser has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [25/06/2011 11:41:04] System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        - The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore(UInt32 Flags, IntPtr hToken, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore..ctor(ComponentStoreType storeType, SubscriptionStore subStore)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore..ctor(String deployPath, String tempPath, ComponentStoreType storeType)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.get_CurrentUser()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: 32 bit or 64 bit Windows 7?

Comment: Try right clicking on the standalone installer and clicking "Run as administrator".

Comment: Important line here is "The system cannot find the file specified" check to make sure you have permissions to install programs and make sure that your disk is clean with a chkdsk.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Portable version of Chrome
http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way to install Chrome

http://www.google.com/support/installer/bin/answer.py?answer=126299&&hl=en

Comment: Tried that alternative installer but arrive at same error message. It's almost as though Internet Explorer 9 is prohibiting the deed.

Comment: Do an IE reset, Internet Options>Advanced Tab

Comment: @purir, But IE has nothing to do with it if you use the standalone installer.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome uses ClickOnce to install. It is reportedly a permission error, that can be fixed by deleting `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat` - though with another (administrator) account, since it is locked if the user is logged in. I would personally recommend you rename it to something, e.g. `UsrClass.dat.bak`, so if something goes wrong or it doesn't work you can restore it.

See for more info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/ef690458-22bc-4d72-a36c-773c1cc6fa15/

Possible alternative solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779043/filenotfoundexception-during-clickonce-install-missing-hkcu-software-classes-so

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file and then open outside IE